# Сбор и сливание данных 2 таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Есть 2 таблицы.

1. `storage` должна выводить все записи с where `userid = 1`
2. `storageAdd` должна выводить все записи с where `userid = 1`

Полученные данные из таблицы `storageAdd` добавляются в `storage` используя поле `storageAdd.storageid`.

Допустим у нас 3 записи в `storage`:

1. id = 1, userid = 1, name = 'выводим'
2. id = 2, userid = 2, name = 'искомое'
3. id = 3, userid = 2, name = 'то, что не надо'

Есть одна запись в `storageAdd`:

id = 1, userid = 1, storageid = 2

Конечный результат должен содержать 2 записи с id 1 и 2.

Comment: не совсем понятен второй запрос `union`. У Вас там нет фильтрации по `userid`. Получится, что второй запрос вернет все из `storage`. Это Вы просто не дописали?

Comment: и еще, что хоть Вы и вводите `StorageAdd` в оба запроса,  они оба ввдены с `LEFT JOIN`, и ни из одного из них данные в результат не приходят. Это как? Может кинете пример данных обеих таблиц?

Comment: мой запрос, как оказалось, просто выводил все записи из `storage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM storage WHERE userid = 1 UNION SELECT s.* FROM storage as s INNER JOIN storageAccess as a ON a.storageid = s.id WHERE a.userid = 1;
```

Смог получить желаемое вернувшись к UNION, как бы мне это не нравилось.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что я правильно понял вопрос... но все-таки вот такой вариант Вам не подойдет?

```
SELECT s.id,s.userId,s.fileid,s.name,s.access,s.token, a.*
FROM storage as s
LEFT JOIN StorageAdd as a ON a.storageId = s.id  AND a.userid=s.userId;
```

Это покажет все данные из `storage`, плюс, если есть соответствующие записи в `StorageAdd` они будут видны

Comment: Ваш запрос выводит **все** записи из `storage`.
`a.*` только портил вывод добавляя пустые поля.

Вопрос переоформил с примером выводимых записей. Моя вина, что не объяснил толком.

Answer (score 0):

Шаг первый. Джойним данные: таблица *storage* + отфильрованные данные из таблицы *storageAdd*.

Шаг второй. Добавляем фильтры. Нужны только те данные, у которых *s.userid* = 1 или *sa.id* не пусто.

```
   SELECT s.id,
          s.userid,
          s.name 
     FROM storage s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id
             FROM storageAdd 
            WHERE storageid = 1) sa ON sa.storageid = s.id
    WHERE s.userid = 1
       OR sa.id IS NOT NULL;
```